# How to Call a WCF or Window Service From Android Client?

Tags: android, wcf, c#-4.0, windows-services

I have a Android app and I have a button which is used to print documents.
When I press that button I have to call my WCF or Windows service to print that page.

Is it possible and which is better to use - WCF or Window Service?

Answer (score 0):

You can host the print functionality as webservice and access over http. Question is, you want to just print an existig document or transfer the document from android to wcf service over http? The following links might help you.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/361107/WCF-and-Android-Part-II
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP